# How can I select the top level of a hierarchical relationship in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, recursion, recursive-query

I have a list of routines that need to be ran, and a table which defines whether a routine is dependent on the successful completion of other routines or not. So for example:

```
| RoutineID | DependentRoutineID |
| --------- | ------------------ |
|     1     |         NULL       |
|     2     |          1         |
|     3     |          2         |
|     4     |          3         |
|     5     |          3         |
|     6     |          4         |
|     7     |          5         |
|     8     |         NULL       |
|     9     |          8         |
|     10    |          9         |
```

Due to the hierarchical nature of the dependencies, all the routines >= 2 and <= 7 are at their highest level dependent on Routine 1. I want to reflect that in a query that returns the "highest" DependentRoutineID for each RoutineID

```
| RoutineID | DependentRoutineID |
| --------- | ------------------ |
|     1     |         NULL       |
|     2     |          1         |
|     3     |          1         |
|     4     |          1         |
|     5     |          1         |
|     6     |          1         |
|     7     |          1         |
|     8     |         NULL       |
|     9     |          8         |
|     10    |          8         |
```

I've been trying to do this using a recursive CTE but it's not working out as I expected; how can I effect that query?

Comment: Can you post your query attempt?

Answer (score 2):

Try This below Recursive CTE

```
DECLARE @TABLE AS TABLE (RoutineID  INT, DependentRoutineID INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE 
SELECT  1 , NULL   UNION ALL    
SELECT  2 ,  1     UNION ALL    
SELECT  3 ,  2     UNION ALL    
SELECT  4 ,  3     UNION ALL    
SELECT  5 ,  3     UNION ALL    
SELECT  6 ,  4     UNION ALL    
SELECT  7 ,  5     UNION ALL    
SELECT  8 , NULL   UNION ALL    
SELECT  9 ,  8     UNION ALL    
SELECT  10,  9      

;WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT RoutineID,
       DependentRoutineID AS DependentRoutineIDDup,
       RoutineID  As DependentRoutineID1         
FROM @TABLE
WHERE DependentRoutineID IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT t.RoutineID,
       t.DependentRoutineID,
       DependentRoutineID1       
FROM CTE c
INNER JOIN  @TABLE t
ON c.RoutineID = t.DependentRoutineID
)
SELECT RoutineID, 
       CASE WHEN  DependentRoutineIDDup IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE DependentRoutineID1 END DependentRoutineID
FROM CTE
ORDER BY RoutineID
```

### Result

```
RoutineID   DependentRoutineID
------------------------------
1               NULL
2               1
3               1
4               1
5               1
6               1
7               1
8               NULL
9               8
10              8
```

Comment: This works but what is the point of adding the "\" to the value? You could just select RoutineID without the string stuff. Then in the final output a simple case expression would return the right value. Still a +1 as this definitely works. :D